# iPhone: IBAction Causes “Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance” Error

Tags: iphone, ios, selector, viewcontroller, ibaction

I am developing an iphone application where you log in  a server and after you get validation my app moves you to another viewcontroller where you can use a button to send your gps location. For some reason when I press a button in my next viewcontroller I get this error :

```
Administrator[3148:c07] -[UIViewController SendGPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88b58d0
2013-01-08 16:01:21.662 Administrator[3148:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController SendGPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88b58d0'
```

If I apply my gps code-buttons in a single viewcontroller it turns out to work fine but when I use my app with the two viewcontrollers when the first one redirects you to the second one (if only you log in to the server) I get this mistake.I move to the second viewcontroller through a condition where I check the response from the server. This is the code which i use to change viewcontrollers :

```
NSString *compare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"true"];

    if ( [compare isEqualToString:string])  {

        UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:FourthViewController.view];   }
    else
        NSLog(@"validation not complete");
```

and this is my button where i use an NSTimer:

```
-(IBAction)SendGPS:(id)sender
 {
     Timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self  selector:@selector(requestIt) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

Any thoughts? thanks in advance!

Comment: paste your requestIt function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The incorrect part of your code is obvious, this is how you initialize your view controller:

```
    UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

And that is creating a new view controller object, fresh from Apple's code, that has no Chuck Norris' idea what the method `SendGPS:` is. Because you obviously created a new view controller subclass called '`FourthViewController`' that implements `SendGPS:` in your Xcode project. You are creating an instance called '`FourthViewController`' but it doesn't actually point to that class, its a `UIViewController` class as you specified.

The correct code should be:

```
    FourthViewController *myFourthViewController = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

You really need to figure it out, I don't think you understand Objective-C, pick up a book, get reading, and do it right!

Comment: Indeed that was the case. Really bad mistake although that code came from an answer where i was trying to figure out how to access properly a new viewcontroller. Anyways thanks for your help and the advice.

Comment: That's fine, glad I helped. We all make mistakes... Even typos that cause you a weeks worth of debugging, stress and frustration - my experience!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
UIViewController* FourthViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

with

```
FourthViewController* FourthViewController = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Also check whether you have declared `SendGPS` function in your .h file

Hope it helps you